# How to configure vue apollo InMemoryCache

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, apollo, vue-apollo

i'm using vue-apollo and have configured it using apollo.config.js file like described here: https://vue-apollo.netlify.com/guide/installation.html#ide-integration (i use VSCode).

Now i need to configure the `InMemoryCache` to not add the `typeName` (`addTypename: false`) as described here: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/caching/#configuration

How can i do this in apollo.config.js? Is this even possible there? Do i need to config it manually without this config file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer here: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/references/apollo-config/#clientaddtypename

```
client: {
    addTypename: false,
```